# How can I check if a model has papertrail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have an active record model class "Post" that might or might not have paper_trail.

How can I programmatically find out if it is paper_trail enabled?

I tried things like:

```
Post.has_paper_trail?
Post.paper_trail.enabled?
```

I have been looking at the source of paper trail but can't find a way to check for this.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a special method for this `PaperTrail.request.enabled_for_model?(Post)`.

Comment: This seems better.